Confluent Kafka - Producer InitTransaction results in KafkaException
We're a few months into adopting Confluent Kafka, specifically using the C# library https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet. The nature of our domain means we're electing to use transactional patterns to ensure Exactly Once semantics, embracing a consumer-transform-produce pattern in some cases.
We're also exploring how to handle failure scenarios, exploring how traditional deadletter mechanisms might enable us to able to support selective event replay. And this is where we're are having a problem.
In our IoC, we register two producers, that for all intents and purposes looks like this (pseudo):
services.AddSingleton<KafkaConnection>()
services.AddSingleton<IHandle<PublishMessage<string, SuccessType>>, MessageProducer<string, SuccessType>>
services.AddSingleton<IHandle<PublishMessage<string, FailureType>>, MessageProducer<string, FailureType>>

As noted, the above is Pseudo, but the net desired outcome is that when some internal behaviour succeeds, we use a MessageProducer and send out an event (e.g. TypeA) to a given topic (TopicA). In a failure scenario, we use a different instance of a MessageProducer to send the original event that was received from the source topic to {sourcetopic}_dlt.
Each instance of a MessageProducer calls InitTransaction internally and sometimes, that results in a KafkaException. The KakfaConnection passed into to each instance of the MessageProducer is the same KafkcConnection instance (singleton) and is set up with the same ProducerConfig, including the same TransactionalId.
I believe that we're calling InitTransaction (only once) but in each instance (2 instances) of the MessageProducer, with the same TransactionalId, which is causing the KafkaException. Sometimes this works, other times it doesn't. But I think the setup is wrong.
So my three questions are:

What's the correct setup? Am I right to think that even though we have two logical 'producers' in my service, producing to two topics (success topic and dead letter topic), there is only one service, and therefore we should be calling InitTransactions only once (irrespective of however many logical producers we have). i.e. A producer = a deployed service producing to Kafka.

What should the TransactionalId be in a horizontally scaled scenario. i.e. I have a service performing a role but 3 instances of that service in a horizontally scaled scenario, with each instance belonging to the same consumer group (hence same role). Should each instance have the same TransactionalId or a distinct TransactionalId?

Maybe we're also missing something with selective event replay also. In a pub sub model (1 producer, 2 consumers for example) with other messaging platforms, it's felt easier to achieve selective replay into only the consumer that failed through 1st class event replay. I'm not sure how easy this is to with Confluent Kafka. We're trying to come up with some suitable patterns that aren't dependant on other members of staff being highly skilled / knowledgeable with the Confluent CLI + having to have the ability to run CLI commands against a production cluster. Any tips would be gratefully appreciated.


Api docs from here : https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/IProducer.cs#L286
InitTransaction: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Producer.cs#L1048C21-L1048C37
